# How to prevent notification showing up when an event in my calendar is occurring?

Tags: calendar, notification-bar, automation

When I have an event (mostly meeting) happening, I only touch my phone when I need to do something that serves that event like taking a photo or a note. If someone messages me in Facebook or email, I want to temporarily turn off those notifications until my job is done. I don't want to block the apps or turn off wifi because sometime I need open those apps to get the information I need. I am aware of a lot of blocking notification apps, but all of them are based on a fixed schedule, not automatically and flexibly turning notifications off based on my calendar.

So, in short:

- Automatically turning notifications off when an event starts
- Automatically turning notifications on when an event ends
- Calendar is updated on a regular basis (I use Google Calendar)
- Only direct call is allowed

My phone is S4 Mini, with CyanogenMod 4.

Comment: I don't know of any on-board configuration for that – but there are several apps available claiming to solve your issue. I've not tried any of them, but you might wish to take a look at [my corresponding lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications) (check the "filter" and "settings" sections on the linked page).

Answer (score 0):

Their is a notification program in android already if you are on Android 4.4+

4.4+ ... Hold on the notification and go to app info, Then deselect show notifications

5.0+... Hold on the notification and select hide notifications from this app or notifications like this !

Then manually turn the apps back on again !

The notification manager is in different sections of the settings for each device.. Some it is under display and others it's under privacy (sms reasons)

Comment: I know how this works. However, I don't want to hide them at all. I just want to **automatically** turn them off when I have an event in my calendar